# Finding which node that has the least maximum distance to all the other nodes in a graph using BFS?

Tags: data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

I made this function some days ago to find the diameter of a graph using BFS:

```
dist[v] = 0;
queue<int> next;
next.push(v);

int bdist = 0; //biggest distance
while(!next.empty()) {
    int pos = next.front();
    next.pop();
    bdist = dist[pos];

    for(int i = 0; i < graph[pos].size(); ++i) {
        int nghbr = graph[pos][i];
        if(dist[nghbr] > dist[pos]+1) {
            dist[nghbr] = dist[pos]+1;
            next.push(nghbr);
        }
    }
}

return bdist-1;
}
```

How/what do I change in the code so that instead of getting returned the diameter, I instead   get returned the node that has the least maximum distance to all the other nodes? What will the new code look like?

Comment: what do you mean by least maximum distance to all nodes , please elaborate

Comment: @VikramBhat for all nodes find a node with max distance from it and then amongst these all max choose the one with minimum

Comment: @sasha _"this is perfectly valid question"_ It's not. There's no effort shown in debugging that code, or doing an attempt of what's requested. It's not much better than just saying _"Gimme teh codez plz"_

Comment: @Paul your function, will it be called for each node ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he has given some code there , dont be so rude

Comment: @VikramBhat I'm not rude, just realistic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I see your point now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are calling the function **biggest_dist** for each node ( Also i guess you should return bdist not bdist-1). So for each node you get the distance of the maximum node from this node. So here is the pseudocode to get the node with minimum maximum distance

```
     /*g is your graph */
     /* This code goes in your main */
     /* assuming 0 based indexing of nodes */
     answer = 0 /* stores your answer, let node 0 be the answer we will update it */
     dis    = biggest_dist(0,g) /* stores the maximum distances of node 0 */
     for each node 
           maxdist = biggest_dist(node,g)
           if maxdist < dis:
              dis = maxdist
              answer = node

     print answer /* your answer */
```

Remember there can be more than one answer, this prints any one of them. Also as suggested by others you should edit your question to reflect your efforts. 
**EDIT** 
This algorithm  has complexity **O(EV+V^2)**. If you use floyyd warshall to compute shortest distances between all from which you you get your answer easily it would be **O(V^3)** and using
dijakstra's would be **O(EV+V^2logV)**. Now as in a simple graph **E** can at max be **V^2** I would go for algorithm given by you if I have to reduce time complexity.

Comment: @Paul I answered in EDIT

Comment: so your algorithm is the best one can do , but if its a special graph like DAG then surely time complexity can be reduced